# R Solver Simple Minimizer

Tags: r, solver, minimize

In Excel there exist a easy solution to this problem --> Solver. I now want to perform the same task in R. First my data:

```
library(data.table)

date <- seq(2015, 2024, 1)
t <- seq(1,10,1)
balance <- c(33, 28, 23, 19, 17, 14, 12, 9, 8, 7)

mydata <- data.table(cbind(date, t, balance))
```

I now want to fit a non-linear line on "balance" with only one parameter (estimated line). The estimated line is defined as follows:

Estimated output for `t[2015;2024]= balance(t=2015)*(1-x)^t`.Thus we know balance and we know t. I am looking for an constant x which minimizes the sum of squared errors of observed balance - estimated balance over all `10` years.

Is there a easy way of estimating this? A way which is comparable to Solver in Excel?

Comment: "minimizes the sum of absolute errors" That's really unusual. Since you are an Excel user I have to ask if you are sure that this is what you want. It's much more common to minimize the sum of squared errors (and for good reasons).

Comment: Take a look at `nloptr` package, I use it alot and it works much better than Excel version. You will need to calculate the gradients yourself if you want efficiency though.

Comment: And just an advice: Don't use `cbind` inside `data.table` like that. It's not necessary and can have unexpected results.

Comment: Minimizing the sum of squared errors will be indeed probably better. I changed it in the question.

Comment: @DavevanBrecht Unless I am misunderstanding your question, x = 0 will always minimize the error as 1^n = 1 for all n, so estimated(t) = balance(t) so error = 0.

Comment: I do not understand you formula and how it relates to the data you provide. What is `Estimated output`? `t` is never equal to 2015 in your data.

Comment: @Avraham you are right, but the balance should have been fixed at the starting point (2015).

Comment: So I want to find an x in balance(t=2015)*(1-x)^t which minimizes the sum of squared errors between all estimated balances (from the formula) and the observed balance in the vector "balance"

Comment: Wouldn't 2015 be 33*(1-x)^1 as t = 1 in 2015?

Comment: @Roland yes you are right. t are the numerical values in the column t. Balance2015=33, the first value in the vector "balance"
estimated balance (2015) = 33*(1-x)^1
estimated balance (2016) = 33*(1-x)^2
....
estimated balance (2024) = 33*(1-x)^10

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with David Arenburg, and use `nloptr` for almost all optimization, to keep this simple, we can use base `optim` with method = Brent (as this is a one-parameter problem).

Here is your data

```
library(data.table)
date <- seq(2015, 2024, 1)
t <- seq(1,10,1)
balance <- c(33, 28, 23, 19, 17, 14, 12, 9, 8, 7)
mydata <- data.table(cbind(date, t, balance))
```

Now we need to create a function that will return the squared error given the input:

```
error_f <- function(x, mydata){
  estimated_bal <- mydata$balance[1] * (1 - x) ^ mydata$t
  return(sum((estimated_bal - mydata$balance)^2))
}
```

Now, just run `optim` (you could have used `optimize` as well, being that this is a one-variable problem)

```
> Z <- optim(par = 2, fn = error_f, lower = -1e6, upper = 1e6, method = 'Brent', mydata = mydata)
> Z
$par
[1] 0.1304993

$value
[1] 36.55443

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Results:

```
mydata$balance[1] * (1 - Z$par) ^ mydata$t
 [1] 28.693524 24.949040 21.693208 18.862261 16.400749 14.260463 12.399483 10.781360  9.374400  8.151048
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func = function(x) 33*((1-x)^t)
costFunc = function(x) sum((func(x)-balance)**2)
res = optim(0, costFunc)
```

The x you want is stored in `res$par`:

```
> res$par
[1] 0.1305176
```

To have a vizualization for some value of `x` and compare to `balance`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

mydata[, c("func1", "func2","func3","func4"):=list(func(0.2), func(0.15),func(0.1), func(0.05))]
dt = gather(mydata, var, value, balance:func4)


ggplot() + 
geom_line(aes(x=t, y=value, color=var),subset(dt, var!="balance")) + 
geom_point(aes(x=t, y=value),subset(dt, var=="balance"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `nls`:

```
fit <- nls(balance ~ balance[t == 1] * (1-x)^t, data = mydata, start = list(x = 0))
summary(fit)
#Formula: balance ~ balance[t == 1] * (1 - x)^t
#
#Parameters:
#  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#x 0.130499   0.007404   17.63 2.76e-08 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 2.015 on 9 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.426e-07

plot(balance ~ t, data = mydata)
lines(mydata$t, fitted(fit))
```

[image: resulting plot]